# Should I be putting the quote symbol every time someone is saying something?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

Serina saw a reflection of light, now with Aron behind her she searched where she had seen the glistening. “What is it?” he asked “I don’t know it’s almost… All the sudden she stopped and screamed while standing there as if she was paralyzed. Serina what is it? What happened?  “I-I-It was singing” she said in reply. Singing? Well more like there was wind blowing inside causing a whistling sound, it stopped once I let go of it. Aron picked it up but nothing happened, so why doesn’t work when I hold it? Maybe it’s broke. Aron went to give it to her but she jumped back. Just hold it “No!” she yelled, okay then hold it with me. So she did but once they both touched it…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question: Yes, whenever you are directly quoting someone else (even if that someone else is a fictional character), you use quotes. For lengthier quotes, you would 1) use an opening quotation mark at the beginning of the quote, 2) use an opening quotation mark at the beginning of each subsequent paragraph contained within the quote, 3) not use a closing quotation mark until the quote is complete.

Dialogue tends to be written with a lot more white-space, starting a new paragraph with each change of speaker. I believe there is more leniency in where to break things when you're dealing with one actor speaking, acting, and speaking again, as Aron does when he picks up the object.

This is how your story might look with American formatting. (If you're British, please adjust accordingly.)

> Serina saw a reflection of light. Now, with Aron behind her, she searched where she had seen the glistening.
>   "What is it?" he asked.
>   "I don't know. It's almost.."
>   All of a sudden, she stopped and screamed while standing there as if she was paralyzed.
>   "Serina, what is it? What happened?"
>   "I-I-It was singing," she said in reply.
>   "Singing?"
>   "Well, more like there was wind blowing inside, causing a whistling sound. It stopped once I let go of it."
>   Aron picked it up, but nothing happened. "So, why doesn't it work when I hold it? Maybe it's broken."
>   Aron went to give it to her, but she jumped back.
>   "Just hold it."
>   "No!" she yelled.
>   "Okay. Then, hold it with me."
>   So she did, but, once they both touched it, ....

Comment: ohh okay thank you that helps so my formatting needs editing?

Comment: Yes, please review the formatting guidelines, particularly for dialogue. This is one of the trickier parts of formatting literature. Realize that journalism doesn't tend to have as much dialogue in it, though, and they will take different shortcuts due to the constraint of space.

Comment: okay where would you suggest I look for reliance in this area? like books and sites etc.

Comment: A classic resource is [*The Elements of Style*](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Elements_of_Style), by Strunk & White. I went through it in high school and college. You can also refer to Wikipedia's entry on [Style guide](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Style_guide#United_States).

Answer (score 0):

It really varies. Read authors such as Cormac McCarthy (No Country for Old Men), William Gaddis (A Frolic of His Own), or William Faulkner (Light in August) to learn about real variety in punctuation of quoted material. And about other things :-)

Just be consistent (for you are not).

Comment: Okay thanks I am in High school and I wanted to do this for fun and to hopefully help me in my Journalism degree